# In jQuery Mobile how to overide the close button href in Poup Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to change `href` in popup(dialog) close button. jQuery Mobile Automatically generate the `href="#"`. I want to override the `href="myPage"`. How can i override the `href=""`

Code

```
 <div data-role="dialog" id="pageId">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
      <h2>your Heading</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Your Message.</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

In this code jQuery automatically generating code for the close button. How to i override the `href="#"` into my `href=""`.

if i click the close(X) button it want to goes to my link page.

Can any one help me with good solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatically generated close button usually doesn't have an ID.

Try this:

```
$('a[title="Close"]').attr("href","http://www.yournewurl.com");
```

### Update

I made a quick working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dYB3a/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
$('#ElementID').attr("href","http://www.yournewurl.com");
```

Comment: in Jquery mobile popup close button. If I click means it goes to previous page(Like back). But if i click the close(X) button it want to goes to my link page.